# Creating a Rule on a subfolder from a parent folder with a rule

Tags: javascript, alfresco

So I have the following challenge.  I have a folder in Alfresco being created or dropped into a folder with a managed rule. I have set the rule to NOT apply to subfolders so it will only apply to the folder being created within it.

Once that is completed, I am using the naming convention of the folder (firstname_lastname_referenceid) to populate its metadata.  What I would like to do is from that point, any children created in that new folder should have the Aspect applied and then the metadata from that new folder be copied to the children.
I was thinking maybe there is a way to apply a rule to that new folder once it is created from the a rule on the parent folder.

Does anyone have any thoughts or experience with this or maybe another way to accomplish this?

I tried doing this from the parent folder rule, but it requires a very complicated script to determine at which level the children are at in relation to the new folder

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is more ways to do it. You can write own behavior which will do that. Or you can write another rule that will be apply for subfolders and in it just ignore first level of folder. I think it will be not so complicated if you have static path to first level folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by using the above mechanisms a little differently (so it's more of a logic than an Alfresco challenge).:

- In the parent folder you

  - set a folder rule *with* inheritance, which calls a java script and
  - an aspect (e.g. `foo:filingRoot`).
- in the script fired by the rule you check on the node, which fires the rule

  - if it's a folder having the 'filing parent' as parent (`document.hasAspect('foo:filingRoot');`) --> populate metadata (which is handled by another aspect e.g. `foo:filingParent`)
  - if one of it's parents has the `foo:filingParent`aspect --> copy metadata from the filingParent as required.

Make sure you always use the same properties you want to search for later by either using the same aspect or by type/aspect inhertance.